# How to use final d = Decimal.parse;

Tags: dart

I am trying to use Decimal from [decimal: ^0.3.5](https://pub.dev/packages/decimal) in my dart project o calculate monetary values. In the readme it shows convenient method to parse values using.

```
import 'package:decimal/decimal.dart';
final d = Decimal.parse;
d('0.2') + d('0.1'); // => 0.3
```

But when I try to use it, it says

> The getter 'parse' isn't defined for the class 'Decimal'.

And in the same note is there better method to make two-dimensional array of Decimal other than

```
List<List<Decimal>> list = [[d("1"),d("2"),d("3")]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Decimal.parse` is a factory (like a constructor) and not some value you can get:
https://pub.dev/documentation/decimal/latest/decimal/Decimal/Decimal.parse.html

So you code should be:

```
import 'package:decimal/decimal.dart';

final value1 = Decimal.parse('0.2');
final value2 = Decimal.parse('0.1');
final sum = value1 + value2;
```

About how to generate the List you can do the following if you have a List of Strings which you want to convert to a List of Decimal:

```
import 'package:decimal/decimal.dart';

void main() {
  final strings = ['1', '2', '3'];
  final decimals = strings.map((s) => Decimal.parse(s));
  print(decimals); // (1, 2, 3)
}
```

Comment: I figured as much. But at the bottom of the readme on https://pub.dev/packages/decimal, it shows something similar to my code. Which is kinda confusing. Can you confirm please.

Comment: I can see in the history of the project that Decimal.parse has not always been a factory constructor but was before 0.3.5 a static method which would make the example work. If you want this behavior you can instead use `final d = Decimal.tryParse` since tryParse are still a static method in the latest version of decimal. In Dart, you cannot save a reference to a factory constructor (I think there are a open issue on that?).